# PHPstan has problems finding a method

Tags: php, laravel, phpstan

We use our own OAuth authentication. Now I get the following problem:

```
Call to an undefined method Laravel\Socialite\Two\ProviderInterface::addUserRequestParam().
```

with PHPstan with this code:

```
 /**
     * @return RedirectResponse|Response|void
     * @throws GuzzleException
     */
    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        try {
            /** @var Provider $driver */
            $driver = Socialite::driver(config_string('auth.socialite.driver'));
            $oauthUser = $driver->addUserRequestParam('with_permissions', '1')
                ->addUserRequestParam('with_roles', '1')
                ->user();
     
//
//

}
```

The method addUserParam is located in the vendor directory in this class:

```
class Provider extends AbstractProvider implements ProviderInterface
{
    protected $userRequestParams = [];

    /**
     * add additional query parameters to the user request
     *
     * @param string $key
     * @param string $value
     * @return $this|ProviderInterface
     */
    public function addUserRequestParam(string $key, string $value): ProviderInterface
    {
        $this->userRequestParams[$key] = $value;
        return $this;
    }
```

I now suspect that it is because this method returns ProviderInterface. I tried to fix it with a doctype `/** @method Provider addUserRequestParam(string $key, string $value) */` but it doesn't work. I couldn't find any help on the internet on how to append query parameters to the user request. Therefore, I hope that someone here can help me out.